# Decimal positions in an array? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I've seen this code and it's supposed to be fine, I don't understand why if for example "left + right" is an odd number, doing "a[middle] == 0" doesn't give error because it doesn't exist in arrays decimal positions. Thank you.

```
/** Searches the value 0 within a[left..right].
* Precondition: 0 <= left, right < a.length,
* a[left..right] is sorted in ascending order. */

public static int intercepts(double[] a, int left, int right) {
if (left > right) { return -1; }
else {
int middle = (left + right) / 2;
if (a[middle] == 0) { return middle; }
else if (a[middle] > 0) {
return intercepts(a, left, middle - 1);
} else {
return intercepts(a, middle + 1, right); }
}
}
```

Comment: In Java, applying `/` to two integers gives an integer result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`left`, `right` and `2` are all integers, therefore an *integer division* will be performed and the result will also be an integer. [Integer division rounds toward 0](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2), so all decimals are simply cut off.

[See for yourself](https://ideone.com/1Kv1f6):

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int middle = 5 / 2;
    System.out.println(middle); // 2
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the two operands (`left` and `right`) are integers then integer arithmetic is used. When the division is applied, the remainder of the result will be "rounded" down to zero.

Example

```
5/2 = 2
7/3 = 2 
8/3 = 2
```

See the following article for a better explanation. [Int division: Why is the result of 1/3 == 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/int-division-why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0)